# When I try to set UILabel.text, I get error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I set my UILabel.text in storyboard

[image]:

[image]

But when I try to update the value in my `ViewController.swift`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    func scoreDisplay(score:Double) {
        print(score)
        scoreLabel.text = String(score)
}
```

It says `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.  How is this happening if the value of `scoreLabel.text` is set to 82?  If I do `print(scoreLabel.text)` I get the same error.

Comment: it seems like your score label is nil. It may not be wired yet. Are you calling this method prior to the subviews being laid out?

Comment: I call `scoreDisplay` from `viewDidAppear`

Comment: try calling in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: did you connect the outlet? did you try to set an exception breakpoint to see if these lines of code are causing the error?

Comment: wanna share your project?